# Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit new installation does not start the desktop

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation

After using Ubuntu since 2008, I had problems with some libraries, the OS started having some bugs and took more time to load, so finally I decided to re-install Ubuntu. I installed it from a DVD, and all looked ok, but when I log on, it takes less than a minute to still show the background image, then the mouse pointer disappears, a "System problem detected" (or something similar) window is briefly shown in the left-hand top corner, then the screen turns into black and finally it returns to the log-on screen (the log-on screen works).

So far I never could use Ubuntu 14.04 after the new installation.

The PC has a VIA C7-D processor (i386, at 1,50 GHz), 2 GB of RAM and a 160GB SATA HDD (the hard disk drive can have errors, but it doesn't look that).

Does anyone know what can be the problem??

I've already tried to reinstall it twice (and I tried a second DVD in the try (not install) mode but the desktop and the other functions after logging on are still not working).

Comment: Can you log into a TTY (Ctrl+Alt+F1, enter username and password -> get a terminal; back to TTY7/GUI with Ctrl+Alt+F7)

Comment: Yes, I tried and the terminal works.Moreover, I get a netbook and I tried the 2 DVD there, and they were OK for the try mode (not installation).

Comment: I thimk the real problem can be my Nvidia graphics card. Do you know which cards Ubuntu 14 don't supports?

Comment: I tried using the integrated video card, but it stills not working!

Comment: No, I'm sorry. But google (or DuckDuckGo!) is your friend with such questions. :-)